# How to display closed caption in roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I'm working on a Roku Bright script using scene graph that is going to play HLS videos (VOD and live),
Press option button and set "caption mode: on" but closed caption still not display.
even popup

[image]

showing message "no caption availabel" or "no caption or audio selection availabel"
Same stream I see the subtitles on track 1 when I play out in VLC player.
Bright script code is -

```
inner = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
inner.url = videoUrl
inner.streamformat = "hls"  
inner.StreamBitrates = [1920]
inner.StreamQualities = ["HD"]   
inner.SwitchingStrategy = "full-adaptation"
m.innerVideo.enableUI = false
m.innerVideo.visible = true
m.innerVideo.setFocus(true) 
m.innerVideoTitle.visible = true     
m.innerVideo.retrievingBar.visible = false 
m.innerVideo.enableTrickPlay = false  
m.innerVideo.retrievingTextColor = "#000000" 
m.innerVideo.bufferingTextColor = "#000000"
m.innerVideo.autoPlayAfterSeek = false
m.innerVideo.bufferingBar.visible = false 
m.innerVideo.bufferingBar.opacity = "0" 
m.innerVideoTitle.text = videoTitle
m.innerVideo.content = inner
m.innerVideo.control = "play"
```

Contents of the stream's m3u8 -

EXTM3U
EXT-X-VERSION:3
EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3211072,CODECS="avc1.77.41,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720
chunklist_b2931072.m3u8
EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1231072,CODECS="avc1.66.32,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
chunklist_b1131072.m3u8

Please Help us and provide a better example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to set the subtitle config.
Try this

```
    inner.subtitleConfig = {
        trackName: "eia608/1"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a giving a great solution, this is working for me but I am getting a new error "*** ERROR: Missing or invalid PHY: 'eia608/1'" when video start to play.

Comment: Even I'm also getting the same each time. But CC will work

Comment: The extraneous warning about PHY: 'eia608/1'" seems to be a minor Roku bug. Add your voice to this https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97471 to increase chance of it being fixed